# Wait until curl command has finished

Tags: linux, bash, curl

I'm using curl to grab a list of subscribers. Once this has been downloaded the rest of my script will process the file.

How could I make the script wait until the file has been downloaded and error if it failed?

> curl "http://mydomain/api/v1/subscribers" -u
> 'user:pass' | json_pp >>
> new.json

Thanks

Comment: curl doesn't return until it's finished downloading (or connection error) - the problem is probably in HOW you invoke curl. and the problem is not in the part of the source code you've actually shared. Thus i've voted to close this question as "needs debugging details", specifically the details on how you are invoking curl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comment, curl will not return until requests is completed (or failed). I suspect you are looking for a way to identify errors in the curl, which currently are getting lost. Consider the following:

1. If you just need error status, you can use bash pipefail option `set -o pipefail`. This will allow you to check for failure in curl

```
set -o pipefail
if curl ... | json_pp >> new.json ; then
  # All good
else
  # Something wrong.
fi
```

Also, you might want to save the "raw" response, before trying to pretty-print it. Either using a temporary file, or using tee

```
set -o pipefail
if curl ... | tee raw.json | json_pp >> new.json ; then
   # All good
else
   # Something wrong - look into raw.json
fi
```